# Error installing Package in R Studio

Tags: r, macos

I am trying to install the  SDSFoundations package into R studio in Mac but Its getting an error.

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/SDSFoundations_1.3.tar", repos = NULL)
Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'
```

also I tried the following:

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/SDSFoundations_1.3.tar", repos = NULL, type ='binary')
tar: Failed to set default locale
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try `type = 'source'` instead of `type = 'binary` or (the default) `type = 'both'`.

Comment: thanks!!! this worked great!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `type = "source"`

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/SDSFoundations_1.1_R_x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0.tar", repos = NULL, type = 'source')
```